# WhatsApp doesn't use contact name on lock screen notifications

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, notifications, whatsapp.app

Hello Community Members,

I am using iOS device (iPhone) with latest iOS version.

I am facing an unusual problem with WhatsApp.

When I get message from one of my contacts and screen is locked, WhatsApp shows that I got message from name (name it uses is set by user, and not as saved in my contacts)

Example: If I get a message from my brother, whose contact is saved on my device as "Bro" and if screen is locked, it reads 1 message from Mr. Mehta (which is set by my brother as his display name on WhatsApp)

Anyone facing same issue, or it's just me. If yes, any solution for same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On iOS devices that is the default setting for whatsapp you cannot change it :-/